# Accurate && precise location data within a timeframe (session)?

Tags: c#, beginner, unity3d, geospatial, location-services

## Scenario

A session would start & end within a time frame. Within this time frame,  the device would be moving within a constraint environment. The movement would be extremely slow (slow-walking to stillness).

This session could (& would) be entered & exited several times, although doing just a single session might be sufficient for the user.

## Objective

Once this session is complete, it is the intention to have a location that would help any other user to get to that location.  So during the session, a single location data would be recorded.  The objective is to have the most accurate & precise single location data.

**Device**: any iOS device

## Required parameters

1. [Latitude](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d/1423513-latitude)
2. [Longitude](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d/1423552-longitude)
3. [Horizontal Accuracy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423599-horizontalaccuracy)
4. [Altitude](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423820-altitude)
5. [Vertical Accuracy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423550-verticalaccuracy)

I have a class called as LocationData.cs, where data is being populated whenever there is an update.

// LocationData.cs

```
internal static class LocationData
{
    internal static double Altitude = DummyValue;
    internal static double VerticalAccuracy = DummyValue;
    internal static double HorizontalAccuracy = DummyValue;
    internal static ISN_CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate = new ISN_CLLocationCoordinate2D(0,0);
}
```

Now using the data available, how to figure the best accurate & precise location?

Here is my approach. The following method runs through the entire session.

```
private IEnumerator examineForAccurateAndPreciseLocationData()
{
    do
    {    // Starts when session starts
        assignHorizontalLocationValuesAppropriately();
        assignVerticalLocationValuesAppropriately();

        // This do-while loop runs every 1 second
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    } while (CreateSessionBuffer.ISrunning == true);
    // ends when session is complete
}

private void assignHorizontalLocationValuesAppropriately()
{
    if (LocationData.HorizontalAccuracy < 0)
    { return; }// Just in case if there is an absence of reliable data

    // If accuracy is less than a positive number, it assigns an immediate value
    if (XPHeader.Location.HorizontalAccuracy < System.Double.Epsilon)
    {
        XPHeader.Location.HorizontalAccuracy = LocationData.HorizontalAccuracy;
        XPHeader.Location.Coordinate.Latitude = LocationData.Coordinate.Latitude;
        XPHeader.Location.Coordinate.Longitude = LocationData.Coordinate.Longitude;
    }
    else if (XPHeader.Location.HorizontalAccuracy > LocationData.HorizontalAccuracy)
    { // if there is a better accuracy, then it assigns the value that is available
        XPHeader.Location.HorizontalAccuracy = LocationData.HorizontalAccuracy;
        XPHeader.Location.Coordinate.Latitude = LocationData.Coordinate.Latitude;
        XPHeader.Location.Coordinate.Longitude = LocationData.Coordinate.Longitude;
    }
}

private void assignVerticalLocationValuesAppropriately()
{
    if (LocationData.VerticalAccuracy < 0)
    { return; }

    if (XPHeader.Location.VerticalAccuracy < System.Double.Epsilon)
    {
        XPHeader.Location.VerticalAccuracy = LocationData.VerticalAccuracy;
        XPHeader.Location.Altitude = LocationData.Altitude;
    }
    else if (XPHeader.Location.VerticalAccuracy > LocationData.VerticalAccuracy)
    {
        XPHeader.Location.VerticalAccuracy = LocationData.VerticalAccuracy;
        XPHeader.Location.Altitude = Geo.LocationData.Altitude;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: maybe this would help you out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_standard_location_service

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have applied that information found in that article when I populate LocationData.cs.